# Github Syntax highlight on Markdown not working

Tags: github

GitHub wiki syntax highlight on markdown not working!

Do I need to change my wiki settings?

**EDIT:**

[image: Edit]

**PREVIEW:**

[image: preview]

I think this is not a syntax problem. 
cs, javascript, ruby...every not working. 
Please help me :)

Comment: I think this is not a syntax problem.  
cs, javascript, ruby...every not working.

Comment: It does not work on preview, but is it recognized when you submit the change? On the actual edited page?

Comment: This recently happened to my project and I'm not sure why. Its worked since I first started the repository almost a year ago, but now none of the heading markup works. Before you'd use `#` to specify a heading; now it does nothing!